# Chrome -- update domain in history

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, domain-name

We recently migrated a core web-app from `a.b.io` to `alpha.beta.int.com`.

I'm very used to having chrome autofill help me navigate around this app. For example, I type `gamma` when I want to get to `a.b.io/internal/gamma-team`.

Instead of clearing history and starting from scratch, is there a way to update my history to make all my old navigation shortcuts continue to work, but point me to the new website instead?

Basically is there a way to `sed -i 's/a.b.io/alpha.beta.int.com/g' "chrome_history"` and have that feed back to the autofill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome history is stored for Windows in the folder
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`,
and for the Mac in
`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.

It is found inside an SQLite database file named `History` (no file extension),
specifically in an SQL table named `keyword_search_terms`.
For URL predictions, the table is called 'urls'.

For doing modifications, you will need
an SQLite database utility such as:
[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/),
[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/),
[DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/)
or
[SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) for OS X.